Issue with weight painting and rig
For whatever reason the dress is no longer wrapping around the arm/shoulder part as it should. I have no clue what has happened but I've been at it for ages trying various things but for the life of me, I cannot get the mesh to go back to how it was. I've tried the following:

Applied All Transforms
Applied Rotation & Scale
Checked for bad normals
Applied Reset Vector
Deleted the rig and re-rigged the whole model
Deleted all groups for all objects and re-applied
Deleted all groups for that dress only
Checked for what I would think is influencing the mesh weight
In Edit mode, I moved the arm into an "A" pose thinking it'd help wrap the dress around the arm but it didn't
Messed around with Pose mode and Rest mode
Rigged only that arm

This is now:

How it should look:

I also noticed that if I were to apply weight to the whole dress it for whatever reason rotates as if it's copying the bone rotation:

I'm so lost on what to do :(

hello could you please share your file? https://blend-exchange.com/

You’re supposed to edit that into your question, not comment it. It’s still usable as is I think. Meanwhile, open the properties area of the 3D Viewport, and in edit mode select one vertex of the sleeve. The properties area should list what vertex groups it’s a part of. What do you see?

Ignore my previous comment. I mixed it up with another.
On the sleeve, I only see one vertex group called, forearm.L Clicking around I see other groups.

Maybe join the collar to the dress, then in Edit mode move up the edge and collar like that:

Remove all these vertices from all groups:

Paint the weight of each bone in Weight Paint mode:

change the

Thanks, I did this and it worked.
